# Is it possible to go from tree climbing to hiding in sand like some sandlions do

Tags: biology, creature-design, evolution, aliens, environment

Is this evolutionary path possible with this creature because I don't know what would be in order to go from a creature that lives in the trees to living in a treeless environment. I had an idea that these creatures had a separate lineage that would get stranded on a island because the continents on my planet were shifting and in the island they were on now has hot temperatures and not many trees. After millions of years it would become a desert like environment. I already know that they can dig they do it to hide their eggs so why not use that to avoid the heat. They would eventually become smaller and would have a dusk to dawn like lifestyle. This is because they hibernate to avoid the heat (is that right?) and when its time they leave to hunt, drink water, courtship etc.if this isn't possible then i could use this for another creature.[image]

Comment: Just for clearity.. your drawing.. am I correct your creature looks asymmetric ? It has daggers on its feet only on one side, and a rudimentary left arm ? or is it just the perspective, the arm stretched backward, did you not finish the drawing ?

Comment: yes i did and its perspective.the creature has six limbs and two pedapalps on the front of the torso.it is symmetrical and the reason it has limbs like that is because i took insperation of a cocanout crab and has one claw on each limb besides the pedapalps and the other limbs or grasping the tree so it wont fall hope this helps

Comment: Please note that the answer to the question "can X evolve?" is for all practical purposes always "yes." Given enough time anything can evolve into anything. Just to round out the discussion, "How can X evolve?" is IMO way to broad to answer on this site (giving someone a multi-million year history is a bit much). "What evolutionary pressures could rationalize X?" is much more practical on this site as it's a finite list of things that meet a specific need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely possible. You just have to have the trees dissappearing, or the ecologic tree niche closing up in another way (maybe because of fitter predators moving in?) - then your creatures lineage is free to drift towards greener pastures, or in this case underground trapping.

How about combining the sand-angle and the tree-angle? Your creature is top notch at trapping in trees, but then a climatic shift gives rise to a desertification of the environment, sand is accumulating and the trees cannot cope. So there is less and less trees, and more shrubs and your creatures lineage gets more and more adept at trapping on the ground. The ones with the best adaption to moving sand get an extra boost, because now there is a lot of sand, and thus as soon as an in-sand trapping behavior is premiered, that works quite well, perhaps at first still incorporating twigs and later going all-sand.

To repeat: All you need is an evolutionary pressure towards your ideal creature, and a pressure away from the way the antecedents did it, and you are all set (in reality the creatures would also need beneficial mutations as 'steps' on their way to a new ecological niche (and would need them faster than any competing species that might end up in that niche), but in your story we can take that as a given)

Comment: thank you for the comment this helps